# How to modify the return result on fetchone SQLlite

Tags: python, sqlite

How to modify the result  {"userName":"JohnChongw"} to JohnChongw only?

```
cur.execute("SELECT userName FROM socialmedia WHERE email=%s", [email])
            user1 = cur.fetchone()
            session['userName'] = user1
            return session['userName']
```

Comment: ``return user1`` ?

Comment: I mean return the userName from database, because it return the result like this {"userName":"JohnChongw"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are using row_factory:

The row object can be accessed by:

```
user1 = cur.fetchone()['userName'] #this will be just the string data.
```

Otherwise depending on your set output method that you define when connecting to the sqlite database it might be a tuple insteadl. But I am willing to guess that db.row_factory = sqlite3.Row. If it isn't please let me know and I will add the alternative.